# Fast Video Compression on Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, compression, libx264

I want to upload video files to server and compress before uploading. I'm using ffmpeg libx264. I have seen viber can upload 30 second video file of size 78MB within a minute [reduce it's down to 2.3MB]. I want to know how do they do it so fast?

What I have tried so far -

```
FFMPEG version :  n2.4.2 
Built with gcc 4.8

Build Configuraiton : --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
```

Command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/main.mp4 -s 480x320 -r 20 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -c:a copy -me_method zero -tune fastdecode -tune zerolatency -strict -2 -b:v 1000k -pix_fmt yuv420p /storage/emulated/0/output.mp4
```

The result so far is, a 30second 78MB file gets compressed to 4.3MB which takes around 1min 28seconds. Here is the console dump - http://pastebin.com/rn81acGx . I mainly want to reduce the time it takes to compress. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

## x264 cpu capabilities

Your `ffmpeg` console output/log shows the following message from libx264:

```
using cpu capabilities: none!
```

For your device I would expect something like:

```
using cpu capabilities: ARMv7 NEON
```

You should re-evaluate how you compiled `x264` so it properly supports the capabilities of your CPU. With `none` it encodes significantly slower.

- Do not use the `--disable-asm` configure option for `x264`.
- After you run `./configure` for `x264` the console output should show `asm: yes`.
- Use a recent `x264`. I see many users compiling old versions that may miss out on optimizations.
- Then recompile `ffmpeg` so it uses the new `x264`. Make sure `ffmpeg` does not link to the wrong `x264` if you have multiple versions.

## MediaCodec hardware acceleration

`ffmpeg` currently supports hardware assisted H.264 and HEVC *decoding* via the MediaCodec API in Android which may help decrease the overall processing time. For more info and an up-to-date list of capabilities see [FFmpeg Wiki: Hardware Acceleration](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro).

To use it ensure your `ffmpeg` is compiled with `--enable-jni` and `--enable-mediacodec`.

Comment: Have you ever managed to get "using cpu capabilities" to show anything but none for FFMpeg on Android? We have recompiled, with --enable-jni and with --enable-mediacodec but did not help. According to the page you linked, it only helps with the decode as there is no encode support with MediaCodec.

Comment: @BradMoore It's a message from x264, not ffmpeg, so you'll have to compile x264 properly. I don't have any ARM devices, and too lazy to try QEMU, so I can't provide any specifics.

Comment: Anyone managed to get "using cpu capabilities" to show anything ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use the hardware accelerated encoding capabilities of the device, if any. As far as I can tell `ffmpeg` doesn't offer HW accelerated encoding on Android. There is a `libstagefright` but it's used for HW decoding.

Depending on your target API version you may be able to use [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) (API 16) to do HW encoding and [MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) (API 18) to mux into `mp4`. If you manage to encode with `MediaCodec` you could use `ffmpeg` to do the muxing part, which would require only API 16.