# Resize and overlay image on video in android efficiently

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to resize image and video(2160 x 3840) to a same resolution(540 × 960) and then overlay image on video for whole time. This whole process is similar to capturing video and adding caption to it like snap-chat and saving it.

Since i am successful in doing so using *FFMPEG library* but it consumes considerable amount of time in processing.

I have searched the internet for other faster operations but no luck.  I will post commands that i am using.

```
//1st command (video size from 59MB to 4MB, about time 110secs)
-i sdcard/VID_20161228_174315.mp4 -vf scale=540:960 sdcard/output540.mp4
//2nd command (image file , size done, time : a sec hence ignored)
-i sdcard/capture.jpg -vf scale=540:960 sdcard/capture540.png
//3rd command (time 80sec)
-i sdcard/output540.mp4 -i sdcard/capture540.png -filter_complex overlay=0:0 -r 30 sdcard/output_overlay.mp4
```

So here using -preset and copying same audio from source did not work as expected.

**Questions:**

1) Should i use specific codec ?

2) How to achieve Minimum time for processing?

3) Will applying multiple threads help? If yes then how? I want this process to work in background even if app is closed.

4) All other options that can combine to make an efficient solution?

Log for 3rd command:

```
 SUCCESS with output : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                      built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                                      configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                                      libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                                      libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                                      libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                                      libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                                      libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                                      libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                                      libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                                      libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                                    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'sdcard/output540.mp4':
                                                                      Metadata:
                                                                        major_brand     : isom
                                                                        minor_version   : 512
                                                                        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
                                                                        encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
                                                                      Duration: 00:00:10.09, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 2055 kb/s
                                                                        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 540x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 1930 kb/s, 16.75 fps, 16.75 tbr, 17152 tbn, 33.50 tbc (default)
                                                                        Metadata:
                                                                          handler_name    : VideoHandler
                                                                        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 119 kb/s (default)
                                                                        Metadata:
                                                                          handler_name    : SoundHandler
                                                                    Input #1, png_pipe, from 'sdcard/output_540.png':
                                                                      Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
                                                                        Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 540x960, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
                                                                    [libx264 @ 0xaca425f0] using SAR=1/1
                                                                    [libx264 @ 0xaca425f0] using cpu capabilities: none!
                                                                    [libx264 @ 0xaca425f0] profile High, level 3.1
                                                                    [libx264 @ 0xaca425f0] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=9 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
                                                                    Output #0, mp4, to 'sdcard/output_overlay_forlog.mp4':
                                                                      Metadata:
                                                                        major_brand     : isom
                                                                        minor_version   : 512
                                                                        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
                                                                        encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
                                                                        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 540x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
                                                                        Metadata:
                                                                          encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
                                                                        Side data:
                                                                          unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
                                                                        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
                                                                        Metadata:
                                                                          handler_name    : SoundHandler
                                                                          encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 aac
                                                                    Stream mapping:
                                                                      Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
                                                                      Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
                                                                      overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
                                                                      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
                                                                    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
                                                                    frame=   19 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.88 bit
12-29 02:20:37.914 19213-19213/in.techzilla.happenning_client D/Ffmpeg: Finished command : ffmpeg [Ljava.lang.String;@1a223d4
```

here one more txt file for full output

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B60iSiCrzaVkUXFpYVFpdGdKN2M/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Combine commands

Instead of using three commands you can use one:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=540:960[v0];[1:v]scale=540:960[v2];[v1][v2]overlay" -preset ultrafast -c:a copy output.mp4
```

- `-preset ultrafast` will use the fastest x264 encoding preset.
- No need to use `-threads` because it will automatically choose an optimal number.
- The audio is [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-muxed) instead of being re-encoded.

## using cpu capabilities: none!

This indicates that your x264 was not compiled properly. For a typical Android device it should be something similar to `using cpu capabilities: ARMv7 NEON`. You should get a significant boost in encoding speed with the proper CPU capabilities being supported.

#### Also see

- [Fast Video Compression on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33507589/1109017)

Comment: Thank you so much for efforts. i learned new things. i am using this library https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java . but stuck at error. screenshot log is in the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B60iSiCrzaVkR3NnVk1vdXNPOVE/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @BhushanLadhe There was a typo in the example command. Try again. Also, next time copy and paste the text instead of making an image of text.

Comment: sorry for log images. Well in that library double quotes doesn't work. hence i just removed ffmpeg and double quotes from the command. just trying to work it out.

Comment: will you just check how this may work in this app? i know i am asking much, but i am beginner to FFmpeg. https://github.com/writingminds/ffmpeg-android-java/releases/download/v0.3.2/app-debug.apk

Comment: @BhushanLadhe I forgot that Android users have to omit the quotes or something like that. I'm not an Android user, so I won't be of much help with whatever `app-debug.apk` is.