# How can I compress or change the resolution of the video very fast with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to compress or change the resolution of the video before sending it to server but I don't want to take too long. For example for the following code a video with size 100MB it takes 2-3 min to resize it to 10MB. Can I do it faster without losing too much quality?

```
             String[] command = {"-i", filePath, "-vf", "scale=640:360", "-c:a", "copy", "-preset", "ultrafast", dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```

Console output for above command:

```
    05-28 11:50:22.131 23323-23323/com.example.rares.peoplecounterapp D/TestFFmpeg: SUCCESS with output : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                                  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                                                  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                                                  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                                                  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                                                  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                                                  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                                                  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                                                  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                                                  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                                                  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                                                Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20170501_212606.mp4':
                                                                                  Metadata:
                                                                                    major_brand     : mp42
                                                                                    minor_version   : 0
                                                                                    compatible_brands: isommp42
                                                                                    creation_time   : 2017-05-01 18:26:46
                                                                                    com.android.version: 6.0
                                                                                  Duration: 00:00:38.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17203 kb/s
                                                                                    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 17007 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.98 fps, 29.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
                                                                                    Metadata:
                                                                                      creation_time   : 2017-05-01 18:26:46
                                                                                      handler_name    : VideoHandle
                                                                                    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 155 kb/s (default)
                                                                                    Metadata:
                                                                                      creation_time   : 2017-05-01 18:26:46
                                                                                      handler_name    : SoundHandle
                                                                                [libx264 @ 0xf7344400] using SAR=1/1
                                                                                [libx264 @ 0xf7344400] using cpu capabilities: none!
                                                                                [libx264 @ 0xf7344400] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
                                                                                [libx264 @ 0xf7344400] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=9 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
                                                                                Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20170501_212606_compressed97.mp4':
                                                                                  Metadata:
                                                                                    major_brand     : mp42
                                                                                    minor_version   : 0
                                                                                    compatible_brands: isommp42
                                                                                    com.android.version: 6.0
                                                                                    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
                                                                                    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 29.92 fps, 11488 tbn, 29.92 tbc (default)
                                                                                    Metadata:
                                                                                      creation_time   : 2017-05-01 18:26:46
                                                                                      handler_name    : VideoHandle
                                                                                      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
                                                                                    Side data:
                                                                                      unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
                                                                                    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 155 kb/s (default)
                                                                                    Metadata:
                                                                                      creation_time   : 2017-05-01 18:26:46
                                                                                      handler_name    : SoundHandle
                                                                                Stream mapping:
                                                                                  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
                                                                                  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
                                                                                Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
                                                                                frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.04 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s speed=1.96x    
                                                                                frame=   15 fps=
05-28 11:50:22.132 23323-23323/com.example.rares.peoplecounterapp D/TestFFmpeg: Finished command :ffmpeg [Ljava.lang.String;@d8854f
```

Comment: Choose two: fast encoding, small file size, high quality.

Comment: Fast encoding + high quality

Comment: But how whats up or facebook do it? They compress the file right?

Comment: I thought that if I reduce the screen resolution it would be better...the video size is reduced but I don t know how to modify the video faster. It s taking too much time

Comment: I'm guessing limitless capital, a legion of engineers, and acres of servers–I don't think they will reveal their exact methods. First, you should first determine the bottleneck (probably CPU). Try to stream copy the audio with `-c:a copy` instead of re-encoding it, make sure libx264 is actually using your CPU capabilities (the console output will show if it is or not), don't use old ffmpeg and x264, see if other scaling algorithms are faster (`flags` option in scale filter), buy a faster CPU, try distributed encoding, experiment with hardware accelerated decoders/encoders, etc.

Comment: Can you provide a command?

Comment: the file is getting bigger. maybe if I remove the audio from the video the size gets smaller?

Comment: `using cpu capabilities: none!` as I mentioned. If you re-compile x264 properly (and ffmpeg) so it actually lists your CPU capabilities so it shows something like `ARMv7 NEON` instead of `none`, then you will see a significant decrease in encoding time. Duplicate of [Fast Video Compression on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494909/fast-video-compression-on-android).

Comment: I am using [WritingMinds](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) library using Gradle. How can I re-compile x264?

Comment: The title of the library said the library is already compiled with x264: FFmpeg for Android compiled with x264, libass, fontconfig, freetype, fribidi and lame (Supports Android 4.1+). Can you guide me please? https://github.com/writingminds/ffmpeg-android

Comment: I have no experiencing compiling for Android, but `x264_build.sh` in that script uses `--disable-asm`. I don't know why they would include that: disabling ASM will cause slower encoding as you are experiencing. Remove that and try again.